# Wordpress: Selecting only one post type for WP_list_categories

Tags: php, wordpress

Similar to [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287383/filter-wp-list-categories-from-one-custom-post-type)

I've created two custom post types, and now they are happily sharing two taxonomies, but unfortunately wp_list_categories doesn't allow me to list a taxonomy by only one post type.
The code of wp_list_categories relies on get_categories, resulting in an array of categories.
So I produced a wp_query thus:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'taxonomy=123&term=9&post_type=type' )
```

so I could do something like:

```
if (!$query) {
unset $categories[categories]
}
```

but I keep getting a $query even if there are no such posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by cloning the wp_list_categories function, giving it a different name and putting in this code after the line: $categories=get_categories($r):

foreach ($categories as $key => $category){
        $temp = array ( 'post_type'=>$r['type'], 'tax_query' => array(
            array (
                'taxonomy' => $category->taxonomy,
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $category->slug
            )

```
    )
        );
    $pauli = new wp_query($temp);
    if($pauli->post_count==0){
        unset($categories[$key]);
    }
}
```

As you can see, it removes categories that do not have any of the post type you need, and then continues the process as wp_list_categories does normally. You may have to add a filter to ensure the category page/taxonomy page called only displays the post type you want, but this depends on what type of permalink you have.